# Trying to add a custom editable field below the price on some woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization

i found a post online that shows exactly what i need, but its not for my theme and doesnt seem to work. It seems most simple to post the link to the fix i found, and see if anyone knows how to make this work on my theme "accesspress store" or any general theme and ill adapt it to my theme.

basically it adds a box on the product editor page that allows a custom text to be shown right below the main price.

Thanks everyone

[link to fix](https://www.themelocation.com/display-two-currencies-in-woo/?unapproved=5792&moderation-hash=064b338374df6e98401ef08b87560933#comment-5792)

Comment: Consider reading [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Function to render UI in Admin Product add/edit page
 */
function show_custom_price_admin() {

    global $thepostid;

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'    => 'custom_price',
            'name'  => '_custom_price',
            'value' => get_post_meta( $thepostid, '_custom_price', true ),
            'class' => 'wc_input_price short',
            'label' => __( 'Custom Price ($)', 'vg' ),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'show_custom_price_admin' );

/**
 * Function to update custom price Admin Product add/edit page
 *
 * @param int $post_id Product's post id.
 */
function process_product_custom_data( $post_id ) {

    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    $product->update_meta_data(
        '_custom_price',
        wc_clean( wp_unslash( filter_input( INPUT_POST, '_custom_price' ) ) )
    );
    $product->save();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'process_product_custom_data' );

/**
 * Function to show custom price front end page
 */
function show_custom_price_frontend() {
    global $post;

    $custom_price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_price', true );

    if ( $custom_price ) {
        $custom_price = wc_price( $custom_price );

        printf( '<p class="price">%s</p>', $custom_price );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'show_custom_price_frontend' );
```

### Function show_custom_price_admin:

1. This function is hooked to the action `woocommerce_product_options_pricing` which is used to show our custom HTML after price fields
2. The global variable `$thepostid` have the current post's primary key i.e. post's ID
3. The WooCommerce meta box function `woocommerce_wp_text_input` is used to output HTML input box which accepts an array argument
4. You can pass the following HTML properties as an associative array `placeholder`, `class`, `style`, `wrapper_class`, `value`, `name`, `type`, `desc_tip`, `data_type`, `custom_attributes`, `id`

---

### Function process_product_custom_data:

1. This function is hooked to the action `woocommerce_process_product_meta` which is used to save our metadata in the database
2. The variable `$product` holds the product object returned by WooCommerce product function `wc_get_product`
3. The product object method `update_meta_data` is used to update the product's metadata to be clear it's an inherited method of WooCommerce core class `WC_Data`
4. For sanitization purpose we used WP formatting function `wp_unslash` which removes slashes from the input then this data piped to the next function `wc_clean` which is a simple wrapper function of the WP formatting function `sanitize_text_field` but we can also pass array too instead of string data
5. Finally we call the method `save` is used to save the product this also inherited method of class `WC_Data`

---

### Function show_custom_price_frontend:

1. This function is hooked to the WooCommerce product UI rendering hook `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form`
2. In this function we are utilizing WP global variable `$post` which holds the current post object
3. We can access any property of the post object, we accessed post ID by calling `$post->ID`
4. In the function `get_post_meta` using the post id we retrieved meta value stored in the meta key `_custom_price`
5. Conditionally verify is metadata not empty then using WooCommerce formatting function `wc_price` we generated HTML to display our custom price
6. Interpolate the formatted custom price value `$custom_price` into the paragraph tag using PHP function `printf`

---

### Backend:

[image: Backend custom field]

### Frontend:

[image: Frontend custom field]

Comment: Hi @gvgvgvijayan, thanks so much for your time on this! Is it possible to make it a text field instead of a strictly number field?

Also its not showi9ng up on the front end of my site, even when using the 2020 theme, any ideas why? thanks again i really appreciate it!

Comment: As you noted I'm using `woocommerce_wp_text_input` so naturally, it accepts any text not only the number. Just remove this line in the code `$custom_price = wc_price( $custom_price );` so it won't format the content as currency content. Screenshot the front end page with the url.